# Issue with DHCP client/service on boot, works if run manually but with errors

Tags: networking, server, dhcp, arp

I recently followed this guide to get wireless working on a fresh install of Ubuntu 19.10: https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/connect-to-wi-fi-from-terminal-on-ubuntu-18-04-19-04-with-wpa-supplicant#comment-46373

On boot the DHCP service runs and I get this error:

```
ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_inetaddr_changed: fail to get arp ip table err:-52
```

So I Alt-F4, login and run it manually using `sudo dhclient`. I get this error:

```
ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_inetaddr_changed: fail to get arp ip table err:-52
cmp: E0F on /tmp/tmp.Itr1VGx0mk which is empty
```

But then I get an IP and everything seems to work. Here's the output of the log file:

```
-- Reboot --
Mar 02 04:57:03 ubu-serv systemd[1]: Started DHCP Client.
Mar 02 04:57:03 ubu-serv dhclient[806]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
Mar 02 04:57:03 ubu-serv dhclient[802]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
Mar 02 04:57:03 ubu-serv dhclient[802]: Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
Mar 02 04:57:03 ubu-serv dhclient[802]: All rights reserved.
Mar 02 04:57:03 ubu-serv dhclient[802]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Mar 02 04:57:03 ubu-serv dhclient[806]: Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
Mar 02 04:57:03 ubu-serv dhclient[806]: All rights reserved.
Mar 02 04:57:03 ubu-serv dhclient[806]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Mar 02 04:57:03 ubu-serv dhclient[806]:
Mar 02 04:57:03 ubu-serv dhclient[806]: Listening on LPF/wlp3s0/f4:5c:89:b0:4d:7b
Mar 02 04:57:03 ubu-serv dhclient[802]: Listening on LPF/wlp3s0/f4:5c:89:b0:4d:7b
Mar 02 04:57:03 ubu-serv dhclient[802]: Sending on   LPF/wlp3s0/f4:5c:89:b0:4d:7b
Mar 02 04:57:03 ubu-serv dhclient[802]: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Mar 02 04:57:03 ubu-serv dhclient[802]: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.1.5 on wlp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x58943a1f)
Mar 02 04:57:03 ubu-serv dhclient[806]: Sending on   LPF/wlp3s0/f4:5c:89:b0:4d:7b
Mar 02 04:57:03 ubu-serv dhclient[806]: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Mar 02 04:57:03 ubu-serv dhclient[806]: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.1.5 on wlp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x58943a1f)
Mar 02 04:57:06 ubu-serv dhclient[806]: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.1.5 on wlp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x58943a1f)
Mar 02 04:57:06 ubu-serv dhclient[802]: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.1.5 on wlp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x58943a1f)
Mar 02 04:57:06 ubu-serv dhclient[806]: DHCPACK of 192.168.1.5 from 192.168.1.1 (xid=0x1f3a9458)
Mar 02 04:57:06 ubu-serv dhclient[802]: DHCPACK of 192.168.1.5 from 192.168.1.1 (xid=0x1f3a9458)
Mar 02 04:57:06 ubu-serv dhclient[802]: cmp: EOF on /tmp/tmp.5Go3SNkqUg which is empty
Mar 02 04:57:06 ubu-serv dhclient[806]: bound to 192.168.1.5 -- renewal in 40109 seconds.
Mar 02 04:57:06 ubu-serv dhclient[802]: bound to 192.168.1.5 -- renewal in 40109 seconds.
Mar 02 04:57:06 ubu-serv dhclient[1022]: Killed old client process
Mar 02 04:57:06 ubu-serv dhclient[1022]: Killed old client process
Mar 02 04:57:07 ubu-serv dhclient[1022]: DHCPRELEASE of 192.168.1.5 on wlp3s0 to 192.168.1.1 port 67 (xid=0x4484af0b)
Mar 02 04:57:08 ubu-serv systemd[1]: dhclient.service: Succeeded.`
```

How can I have DHCP run successfully on boot?

For reference, my hardware is a MacBook Pro, late-2015.